# How to know the next minor date POWER BI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table with names and I have to assign them dates, the oldest date is assigned to the first name and so on, the most current date is assigned to the last name.

For the first and last name I have no problem because I get the maximum and minimum date but for the dates in between I don't know how to do it, any ideas that can help me?

for the first date use:

```
date1 = CALCULATE( MIN('Flujo Liberación Solped'[CDHDR.UDATE]), ALLEXCEPT( 'Flujo Liberación 
Solped', 'Flujo Liberación Solped'[BANFN],'Flujo Liberación Solped'[T16FS_Estrategias.FRGC1]))
```

Is there a way to get the second oldest date or another way to join them?

```
name
name1
name2
name3

dates
05/05/2022
06/07/2021
07/04/2022
```

I want to get

```
name    date
name1   06/07/2021
name2   07/04/2022
name3   05/05/2022
```